# some Jar files open with double click, others do not

Tags: java, macos, double-click

Have 4 different Java projects, completely independent, and all build a Jar. All created in IntelliJ (2022.2.2 Ultimate) on MacOS (Monterey 12.6), built to target Java 8.

2 of the Jars open as expected by a double click, and 2 do not (error message to check for problems in log files via Console but could never find any).

The Jars all created within IntelliJ as an artifact of the project, and AFAIK the same process and options.

One of the Jars will also not open on the command line with either:

```
java -jar MyJarFile.jar    (the Jar does contain the correct manifest)
java -cp MyJarFile.jar package.mainclass
```

but if you do:

```
unzip MyJarFile.jar
```

to unzip the jar into the current directory then:

```
java package.mainclass
```

starts the application as expected.

No change to the external environment (JAVA_HOME, etc) between any of the projects.

Something has to be different .... but what?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` of a jar that doesn't work?

Comment: A common mistake is code that tries to refer to embedded application resources as if they’re files.  Obviously, jar entries are not files.

Comment: @stunbar Contents of the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file (main class is correct):
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: vwall.VWDemo

Comment: Get popup: Java Application launch failed -- (sometimes, not every time). Followed by message:
Check Console for possible error messages related to ”/Users/jdc/Projects/TMViewer/out/TMViewer.V6.jar”.

Tried searching the logs, but did not find anything.